# Pid of scheduler task in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have added a task to the Scheduler in `app/console/kernel.php`.
Like so:

```
$schedule->command('atomaton:socket_start --port=8080')
     ->withoutOverlapping()
     ->appendOutputTo(base_path().'/atomaton/storage/atnSocket.log');
```

So my question is: How do I find out if that command is running?  Can I get the PID?

Answer (score 1):

I found when you call `withoutOverlapping()` laravel will create a file in `storage/framework/`, like `schedule-xxxxx` which could be detected when php artisan schedule:run for avoiding task overlap.

Tested on Laravel 5.0.

Comment: This helps, thank you.  It still doesn't tell me specifically which scheduled task each file is for (I suspect the `xxxxx` part is the job uid so maybe I can find it that way) and whether they are still running.  I've found that old `schedule-xxxxx` files will keep the process from running again so that's probably how `withoutOverlapping()` is working.